# Shorter references in a Sphinx documentation for a single-package project

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am writing a [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) documentation for a Python project with a single top-level package `my_package`. To reference modules/classes in this package, I currently use

```
:mod:`my_package.my_module`
:class:`my_package.MyClass`
:class:`my_package.my_module.MyOtherClass`
```

These references are then generated as

```
my_package.my_module
my_package.MyClass
my_package.my_module.MyOtherClass
```

My question is: Is there a way of configuring Sphinx so that I can use shorter references, like

```
:mod:`my_module`
:class:`MyClass`
:class:`my_module.MyOtherClass`
```

which generate the references as

```
my_module
MyClass
my_module.MyOtherClass
```

In other words, can I make the top-level `my_package` implicit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include

```
.. currentmodule:: my_package
```

at the top of your rst files, then you can leave this out in references.