# Shorter name for the class link in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

```
.. seealso::

   Class :class:`apps.business.models.Department`
      Explanation goes here

   `GNU tar manual, Basic Tar Format <http://link>`_
      Documentation for tar archive files, including GNU tar extensions.
```

That creates a proper link to the class Department.

[image]

How do I change the HTML output to have a just a single class name, without **'apps.business.models**' prefix?

#### so it reads Class Department in HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is the `~` (tilde) in [standard cross-referencing syntax](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#xref-syntax).

> If you prefix the content with ~, the link text will only be the last component of the target. For example,
>
> ```
> :py:meth:`~Queue.Queue.get`
> ```
>
> will refer to `Queue.Queue.get` but only display `get` as the link text. This does not work with all cross-reference roles, but is domain specific.

There is also the directive `.. currentmodule::` with [some documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py:currentmodule) and an [example in another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26298370/2214933).