# Removing text such as "(x.y.z method)" and "(class in x.y.z)" from genindex.html

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using `sphinx-quickstart` followed by `sphinx-apidoc -o doc_path package_path` and `make html` to create the documentation for my project.

I was successful in doing so, but when I opened the `genindex.html` page from the `build` folder, I noticed that the output was in the following format

```
class_name (class in package.sub_package)
function_name (package.sub_package.sub_sub_package.class method)
```

Since the name of my package and sub packages are long, this way of display is affecting the readability.

Is there a way to remove the content in the parentheses and simply provide the listing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorter name for the class link in Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395174/shorter-name-for-the-class-link-in-sphinx)

Comment: This question is about the contents of the autogenerated alphabetical index. I don't think it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395174/shorter-name-for-the-class-link-in-sphinx.