# Sphinx Documentation, 'shorten path' for automodule

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

I currently have a project which looks like this, I would like to use [Sphinx Documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) to document the functions.
Here is its structure:

```
+ project
|
+- docs
|
+- app -+- orange  -+- routers -+- files (.py)
             |                  |
           other apps           +- helpers -+- util.py
            ...
```

I would like to document the files without the `app.orange.routers`.

Example, I have a file named `test.py` in `app/orange/routers` and it has a `clear()` function. I would like to document `test.clear()` instead of `app.orange.routers.test.clear()`.

I have tried to put `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../app/orange/routers'))` in `conf.py` and the `test.rst` file look like this.

```
Test
====

.. automodule:: test
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

Some files could be documented but some of them could not, I realized their differences are those which could not be documented have similar code which related to importing, such as `from .helpers.util import *`, which the warnings received look like this:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'test'; the following exception was raised:
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have tried to change the automodule in the `test.rst` file to `.. automodule:: app.orange.routers.test` and it works, but this is not what I want.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: I think the best solution here is to add proper metadata (pyproject.toml, setup.py, your call) so that `pip install ./orange` works, and so you don't have to manually mangle your path

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve], it would be easier to help. There have been many questions about "attempted relative import with no known parent package": https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=attempted+relative+import+with+no+known+parent+package

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52395525/2214933