# Hide module paths with sphinx autodoc, autosummary and autodoc_pydantic

Tags: python-sphinx, pydantic, autodoc, autosummary, autodoc-pydantic

I am using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/) with [autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) and [autosummary](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html) to generate documentation for a [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/) model using [autodoc_pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/autodoc-pydantic/).

The model is quite complex and has a lot of sub-models in various files and includes custom types used for validation in a separate file. It is also part of a larger package, but I only want to document this module.

```
mypackage/
  __init__.py
  model/
    __init__.py
    model.py
    submodel.py
    types.py
model_doc/
  _build/
  _autosummary/
  conf.py
  index.rst
```

So `model.py` could look something like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from types import Language
# #: Supported languages
# Language = Literal['de', 'en']
from .submodel import SubModel

class Model(BaseModel):
  #: The language
  language: Language = 'en'
  #: submodel settings
  submodel: SubModel = SubModel()
```

I also `from .model import Model` in `__init__.py`.

Now I have the follwing settings set in `model_doc/conf.py`

```py
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
import mypackage

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinxcontrib.autodoc_pydantic',
]

add_module_names = False
python_use_unqualified_type_names = True

autosummary_generate = True

autoclass_content = 'class'
autodoc_class_signature = 'separated'
autodoc_inherit_docstrings = False
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': True,
    'undoc-members': True,
    'private-members': True,
}

autodoc_typehints_format = 'short'
autodoc_preserve_defaults = True
autodoc_type_aliases = {
    'Pattern': 're.Pattern',
    'Language': 'mypackage.model.types.Language',
}
```

I render with the simple `index.rst` of

```
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :recursive:

   mypackage.model
```

But neither `add_omdule_names` nor `python_use_qualified_type_names` has any effect. I think it has to do with `autodoc_pydantic`, which seems non-trivial, as pydantic messes with meta classes and the like, so just regular `.. automodule::` was not working the the default values and produced strange private member artifacts.

In the sidebar of the rendered docs I get

```
mypackage.model
  mypackage.model.model
    mypackage.model.Model.language
    mypackage.model.Model.submodel
  mypackage.model.submodel
  mypackage.model.types
```

and the page renders roughly like

> ## `mypackage.model.model`
>
> ### *pydantic model* `Model`
>
> *field* `language`: `mypackage.model.types.Language` = 'en'
>
> *field* `submodel`: `SubModel` = `SubModel(...)`

1. the sidebar and the page heading should only show the module or class name not the full path including the package. as per `add_module_names = False`, but it's not working
2. `SubModel` links correctly to the rendered page for that class, whereas the type should be displayed without the module path and should also link to the correct page.  as per `autodoc_type_aliases = {...}` and `python_use_unqualified_type_names = True` config options. note that it also doesn't work for python internal types like `re.Pattern`.

I've tried

- (1) various combinations of `..currentmodule::` in the `index.rst`, which didn't help
- (1) setting `autosummary_generate = False` temporarily and manually inserting `.. currentmodule::` directives into the stub pages, which didn't work
- (2) adding `from __future__ import annotations` to all source files, which did't help

I would appreciate any suggestions on these two problems.

Comment: See the last sentence in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395174/shorter-name-for-the-class-link-in-sphinx/52395525#52395525